# How do I ensure what a remote server is delivering in fact is genuine

Tags: .net, azure, security, cryptography

I have a number of remote servers (Customer owned) that wants to deliver a payload of data to my server.
Now the servers are not represented by a user but they have my remote server code running.
And I cannot guarantee that somebody haven't tampered with the remote server code in order to push bogus data to my receiving server.
How can I ensure what the remote server is delivering in fact is genuine?
The remote server code is written in C# as well as the receiving server code.
The receiving server is in Azure.
EDIT: What I'm basically is asking for are some guidelines/preferred approaches to deal with a B2B scenario.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. How to authenticate against your server? OAuth? Client Certificates?

Comment: Do you see how your question is similar to "how do I make sure that only people who've genuinely purchased this game are able to run it?". And then ask yourself how you're going to solve a problem that the entire games industry struggled with.

Comment: Write a contract with the party that is sending you data and include a clause with fines if they send you bad data. Then you only need to monitor for valid data and profit if/when they slip up.

Comment: Most B2B scenarios will involve *contracts* such that a *technical* "solution" to tampering isn't required

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You just have to make sure your server handles incoming data correctly. Never trust client-side code.

Your question is like asking *"how can I make sure people browsing my website won't send sql injections to my server ?"* : you can't, what you can do however is making sure your web application handles requests in a safe way.

Comment: True @ShellCode, so no guarantees are ever given and never trust client-side code. But server-to-server integration do exist in a lot of B2B scenarios. So how do they approach a more secure exchange of data? Certificates, async encrypt keys?